# Find whole sentence with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would love to expand a selection to whole sentences. But I can't manage to produce the right regex. This is my code so far:

```
var re_string = "[.?!](.*?"+RegExp.quote(selector)+".*?[.?!])"
var re = new RegExp(re_string, "g");
var str = jQuery(wpccparams.selectors).text();
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m)
}
```

Example:

Selection of

```
"urn value to the sc" // [.?!](.*?urn value to the sc.*?[.?!])
```

should give me

*"Unfortunately, it also echoes the return value to the screen, and fails to actually return it to the function that called the filter originally."*

in this text:

".It seems that $post is only available to hooks executing at certain times. I have an “init” hook that needs to pull some data from the database using the $post->ID.So far my only workaround has been to add another filter on the_content, that uses $post to get the information I need. Unfortunately, it also echoes the return value to the screen, and fails to actually return it to the function that called the filter originally.Here is the code that extracts the data I need, but echoes and fails to return the value:"

Not working example: https://regex101.com/r/eS5jD9/2

It should also be possible to select two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[.?!]([^.?!]*?urn value to the sc.*?[.?!])
```

Use this.`.*?` should not match another `.?!`.So use `negated quantifier`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS5jD9/3